# bash logical comparison give the wrong answer for RCS files ending in ,v

Tags: file-comparison

The command `ls -al dog RCS/dog,v` returns

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 simon simon   0 Apr 13 19:25 dog
-r--r--r-- 1 simon simon 191 Apr 13 19:28 RCS/dog,v
```

indicating that `RCS/dog,v` is newer than `dog`,  yet

```
if [[ RCS/$dog* -nt dog ]] ; then echo not older than dog ; else echo older than dog ; fi
```

returns `older than dog`.     Since for a file not ending in ,v this comparison performs correctly it seems to be a problem with files ending in `,v`.    Could somebody suggest how to fix this please?

Comment: Besides not being clear if the `$dog` var is set to anything, globs are not expanded in `[[ ... ]]`: `[[ /e* = /etc ]] || echo no` => `no`.

Comment: Per ancient folk wisdom(?), 'you can't update an old dog with new revisions' :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you're referring to a ***variable*** where your expression expects a ***literal***:

```
if [[ RCS/$dog* -nt dog ]] ; then echo not older than dog ; else echo older than dog ; fi
```

That is,

- This is a variable: **`$dog`**, and if unset, you'll get a something like **`RCS/*`** (or something else instead if **`$dog`** happens to be set to **`cat`**).
- This is a literal: **`dog`**, and **`RCS/dog*`** would match **`RCS/dog,v`**

Comment: Ugh stupid typo, I"m sorry to waste people's time with this.